# Is the function continuous - $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sin x} + \frac{1}{x-1}$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, continuity

I have an assignment in which I have to prove that a function "recieves every real value, where $x\in (0,1)$".

Here is the function:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sin x} + \frac{1}{x-1}$$

I don't know the answer yet, however I wanted to know if the function is continuous. I think it is, with the following proof:

I know that if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous then $f(x) / g(x)$ is continous as well, and the same goes for $f(x) + g(x)$.

Let $f(x)=1$ and $g(x)=\sin x$, they are both continuous and since $x \in (0,1)$, $\sin x\ne 0 $ for every value of $x$, I can say that $\frac{1}{\sin x}$ is continuous as well.

Similairly, I do this for $\frac{1}{x-1}$, and I can say the whole function is continuous.

Am I correct?

I don't know how does this make me closer to proving the argument above, but I have to start with something.

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: You are conceptually correct. But note that you have defined $f$ at first, so you can avoid using $f$ in your following argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your initial step is correct, $f$ is continuous on $(0,1)$. I will assume the domain of $f$ is restricted to be $(0,1)$.

Note that $\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to 1^{-}} f(x)=-\infty$, in other words near 0 and 1 the function takes arbitrarily large (or small) values.

Since the function is continuous and defined on an interval, its image is an interval (the intermediate value theorem). The only interval that contains arbitrarily large and small values is $(-\infty, \infty)$.

Comment: Why is the limit equals $-\infty$? If it is, can't I use the Intermediate value theorem somehow? @sdcvvc

Comment: It's a one-sided limit; $\lim_{x \to 1^{-}} \frac{1}{x-1}=-\infty$. Note that since the function is restricted to the interval $(0,1)$, the values for $x>1$ are not taken into account.

Comment: @Alan regarding intermediate value theorem: Take any number $a$. Since the limit of the function is $\infty$, there is an $x$ close to 0 such that $f(x)>a$, and likewise there is a $y$ close to 1 such that $f(y)<a$. By the intermediate value theorem, there is a $z$ such that $f(z)=a$.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but according to my book the interval has to be a closed one. I still didn't figure that out.

Comment: @Alan Once you have $x,y$ as I said, use the theorem on the interval $[f(y),f(x)]$.

Comment: First of all, thank you again! Let me see if I get it clear. I can use the theorem on the interval $[f(y),f(x)]$? Isn't the required interval supposed to be the domain rather than the range? I thought that the interval should be between $(0,1)$ because that's the domain.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the interval $[y,x]$. Since $f(y)<a<f(x)$, there is a $z$ such that $f(z)=a$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24076/discussion-between-alan-and-sdcvvc).

Answer (score 0):

the function $f$ defined by $$f(x) = \frac1{\sin x} + \frac1{x-1}, 0 < x < 1.$$  both summands are continuous in $(0,1),$ so $f$ is continuous there.

now, $$f(x) = \frac{1}{x} + \cdots  \text{ for  } x = 0 + \cdots$$  therefore  $$\lim_{x \to 0+} f(x) = \infty.\tag 1$$  in the same manner 
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{x-1} + \cdots \text{ for } x = 1 + \cdots$$ which implies 
$$\lim_{x \to 1-} f(x) = -\infty.\tag 2$$

now, $(1), (2)$, continuity of $f$ on $(0,1)$ and the intermediate value theorem allows you to conclude that $f$ takes every value at least once.

Comment: Thank you. The reason I can conclude that from the intermediate value theorem is because the function is continuous also in the interval $[0,1]$?

Comment: @Alan, you mean in the open interval $(0,1).$  that is true. you will need the continuity of $f.$

Comment: Actually I mean the closed interval, since I don't know how the theorem works with open intervals.

Comment: the function $f$ is undefined at the endpoints  $0$ and $1.$ you can apply on the closed interval $[\epsilon, 1- \epsilon]$ and let $\epsilon \to 0$ if you like.